# Why is my android emulator so laggy?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Check out my PC stats:

[image]

Despite this, my android emulator is a lot laggy. Animations are a lot jerky and it's not smooth at all. What should I do to speed up android emulator? I've read this: [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator) and tried things listed but it isn't working.

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Play with the "Graphics" options in "Emulated Performance" in the AVD settings in the AVD Manager for your AVD.

Comment: @CommonsWare it is set to "Automatic". Switching it to "Hardware" has no effect. Switching it to "Software" makes it pathetically slow

Comment: OK, well, that at least eliminates the GPU as being the problem spot. I assume that this is an x86 image that you are using. HAXM seems happy. Is anything else consuming significant CPU time besides the emulator?

Comment: @CommonsWare doesn't look like. CPU remains under 2% when emulator is idle and shoots max upto ~35% when i'm clicking here and there in emulator

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes it is x86_64 image

Comment: Try a regular x86 image (not x86_64) and see if you have better luck.

Comment: I guess that it is your graphics card. That card is way out of date.

Comment: @CommonsWare WOAH! I just downloaded x86 image and it is much much better (though still not really top notch) than 64 bit one. Why is this so?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I think 512 mb graphic card should be enough to power at least an emulator

Comment: Beats me. I never use the x86_64 images.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot can you suggest something ?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot i'm asking about gpu/graphics card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, in your environment, the x86 images perform better than the x86_64 ones. Whether that is tied to your CPU (i5 vs. i7) or something else, I can't say.

Moral of this story: try a variety of emulator images to see what the problem is. CPU architecture, screen resolution, GPU emulation mode, and such all affect performance.